# combining Hover with an If statement in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, if-statement, hover

I'm using the [Cycle plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/) for a slideshow. It's got a built-in "Pause on mouse over" feature, however I want to make the navigation elements change on mouse over as well.

This is easily enough accomplished, but I'd like to maintain the pause/play state. That is, if the user has clicked the pause button I want to do nothing when they mouse over. However if they haven't paused it, I'd like to do something on hover and unhover.

Here's the code for when the click the pause/play button:

```
$('#pauseButton').click(function() {
    $('#news').cycle('pause');
    $('#pauseButton').hide();
    $('#playButton').show();
});
$('#playButton').click(function() {
    $('#news').cycle('resume');
    $('#pauseButton').show();
    $('#playButton').hide();
});
```

My first attempt to accomplish this is such:

```
$('#news div').hover(function() {
    $('#pauseButton').show();
    $('#playButton').hide();    
    $('#paused').css({background:"#ff9000"});
}, function(){
    $('#pauseButton').hide();
    $('#playButton').show();
});
```

The problem is that regardless of whether the user had paused the slide show, mousing-over and then off would unpause the slideshow.

It seems like it should be easy to put an "if" statement in there somewhere but I can't figure out where it would go exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you disable the plugin's "pause-on-mouseover" option then you can do it yourself:

```
//setup a flag to detect if the show should play or not
var pause_show = false;

//pause on mouseover 
$('#slideshow-id').on('mouseover', function () {

    $('#news').cycle('pause');
    $('#pauseButton').hide();
    $('#playButton').show();

//play on mouseleave only if flag is not set to `false` (meaning the pause button has not been clicked)
}).on('mouseleave', function () {

    //if the show has not been paused with the pause button then resume the show
    if (pause_show === false) {
        $('#news').cycle('resume');
        $('#pauseButton').show();
        $('#playButton').hide();
    }
});

//set flag to true (block play on mouseleave) when the user clicks on the 
$('#pauseButton').on('click', function () {
    pause_show = true;
});
$('#playButton').on('click', function () {
    pause_show = false;
});
```

Note that `.on()` is new in jQuery 1.7 and is the same as `.bind()` in this case.

Comment: So I just added in the `pause_show` variable, flipped it as appropriate using the existing code, and encapsulated both of the hover function()s in a `if(pause_show === false) {}`.

Comment: Aye it did. So I wonder whether the proper course of action would be to post what I did and mark it as the correct answer, or just mark your answer as right... yours did lead me to the solution (and I've already upvoted it) but it didn't exactly fill my solution. I am kind of leaning towards the latter out of laziness and appreciation.